# Is it possible to disable wonders?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

I find the mechanic irritating sometimes. Is it possible to disable it so I don't have to bother with wonder racing every game?

Alternatively is there a way to make it so anyone can build every wonder?

Wonder limit?

Comment: Everyone being able to build every wonder would sorta defeat the purpose of them being wonders.

Comment: Yeah that's the point. They would make them like any other building everyone can build. They just take longer by comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No world wonders](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=185720992)

Also a decent alternative: [wasted time converted to usable production](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=321511507)

Answer (score 1):

Wonders are not disable-able in the base game.

I would expect it would be possible to remove them via mods, however.